# How to reference a column in a dataframe through a variable in R

Tags: r, datatable

I'm trying to iterate through columns in an R `data.frame`.

To do so, I'm hoping to write a for loop which loops over the column names and then filters the data.table accordingly with values.

My issue is that given the syntax:

```
df[which(df$XX == y), ]
```

`XX` needs to actually be a column name versus a variable that is a string equivalent to the column name.

Is there a way to loop over the columns via inputting a variable?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data.

Comment: ```DF[DF[[XX]] == y, ]```